# Embed GWT in C++?

Tags: java, c++, gwt, v8

I want to write code in java, compile with GWT and embed output JavaScript into C++ program via v8. Everything seems logical and thus possible. I didn't use GWT before, so i'm not sure. Maybe someone knows whether it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy JavaScript code from GWT output, you only need set the type of obfuscation to PRETTY or DETAILED with "-style" flag of compiler (for better reading). 
You can read more here about [code obfuscation in GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling#Why_is_my_GWT-generated_JavaScript_gibberish?)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, like others have used GWT to produce js run in chrome and ff plugins etc.

Think that gwt core is just a compiler, it gets java code and produces js.

What you need to have in mind:

First is that after compiling, gwt utilizes linkers to wrap the result code in .js or .html files specific to the way that js would be executed, so proly you would have to write a linker (or modify an existing one) to deliver the js code in the way you need.

And second, gwt uses browser implementations for certain things, so maybe you have to select which permutations is more suitable for v8, and perhaps tweak some implementations.